# Swift 他画面からのUserDefaults

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

SwiftのUserDefaultsにおいて

Tab ControllerでつないだListとPostにおいて

PostでUserDefaultsしたdataが再度立ち上げたときにListで表示されません

どうしたらいいでしょうか？

Post

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class PostVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    var data: [String] = []

    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func cellAdd(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let list = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as? ListVC else {
            print("Cannot get listVC from tab bar controller")
            return
        }

        let postText = textField.text ?? ""
        list.data.insert(postText, at: 0)

        userDefaults.set(data, forKey: "DataStore")

        userDefaults.synchronize()

        list.tableView?.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    }

}
```

List

```
import UIKit

class ListVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var data: [String] = []

    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        // <TableView初期設定>
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        data = readData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let postcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postcell")!
        postcell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return postcell
    }

    func readData() -> [String] {
        let dataArray = userDefaults.array(forKey: "DataStore") as? [String] ?? []
        return dataArray
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

クラス`PostVC`

```
@IBAction func cellAdd(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let list = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as? ListVC else {
        print("Cannot get listVC from tab bar controller")
        return
    }

    let postText = textField.text ?? ""
    list.data.insert(postText, at: 0)

    userDefaults.set(list.data, forKey: "DataStore") // data => list.data

    userDefaults.synchronize()

    list.tableView?.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
}
```

上のコメントをつけた行を書き換えてください。単純なミスです。

Comment: dataはファイル間で共有できるとみたのですが

Comment: 「マスクをしていさえすれば、コロナウイルスに感染しない」というのと同じくらい、根拠がありません。それよりも、`data`を`list.data`に書き換えて、意図通りになったのですか、ならなかったのですか？その報告をまずしてください。（それと、「ファイル間」でなくて「クラス間」ですね）

Comment: もっともですね List.dataに書き換えてなりました